# Adobe AEM - Including Third Party Jar with Dependencies (Target SDK)

Tags: java, maven, osgi, aem, osgi-bundle

We have a maven project that is composed of several subprojects. These projects are deployed as bundles to an AEM instance. I am attempting to include Adobe's Target SDK into some of the bundles.

As usual, I added the Target SDK dependency to my pom.xml and imported it into one of our customer service classes. When I publish the bundle, I get an error on the Web Console:

```
com.adobe.target.delivery.v1.model -- Cannot be resolved
com.adobe.target.edge.client.model -- Cannot be resolved
```

In an effort to resolve the above, I added the following to the `maven-bundle-plugin` configuration:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<exportScr>true</exportScr>
<instructions>
<Embed-Dependency>target-java-sdk;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
<Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
</instructions>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, this creates another error due to the dependencies of the Target SDK:

```
com.adobe.experiencecloud.ecid.visitor -- Cannot be resolved
io.github.jamsesso.jsonlogic -- Cannot be resolved
kong.unirest -- Cannot be resolved
```

So, I added the appropriate IDs to the above `<EmbedDependency>` configuration. This fixed those errors but resulted in *more* errors based, presumably, on the dependencies of those dependencies.

Having to explicitly define a chain of dependencies in the maven plugin config is obviously far from ideal. Adobe does not seem to offer the SDK as an OSGI bundle. What is the proper way to handle such a situation? I have done research, but many articles were quite dated, and I could not find a good solution for JARs themselves that depend on other JARs.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you solve this? I usually exclude dependencies that are not really needed.